# Sms received from iOS14 phones show "@" as "¡"

Tags: php, sms, ios14

Our website has a function to receive sms from our clients. Some client send sms with their email address, the system has working find for the last 10 months. Today we found out that the email from some sms look like this:

```
name¡gmail.com
```

Notice the `@` is encoded differently and it show as `¡` (look like a reversed exclamation mark).
I used [utf8 encoder](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-encode) and it shows `\xc2\xa1`

After some investigation, we found out that those message from iOS 14 phones (we tested using iOS 13 and Android, those are working fine).

How to convert it back to `@` character? Our system use PHP.

Comment: You should not convert it back to a '@', but stop converting it from an '@'.  Find out what is actually send, and i think it is still an '@' that is being send. (i cannot test, i dont have iOS)

Comment: Those messages are probably send in a diffferent encoding. GSM-7 and UCS-2 are the two most “popular” ones. Your code to actually receives those messages should be able to detect and handle that.